# Is it grammatically correct to use the word 'your' before a verb in present progressive tense?

Tags: tenses, present-progressive

Can I say:

> I understand ***your wanting*** to wait a while longer.

I have heard it being said, but how correct is it?

Comment: None of the clauses in the sentence is an example of the present progressive construction. _Wanting_ is just the verb of a gerund clause, with a possessive subject _your_. One could also say _my wanting, his wanting, her wanting, their wanting,_ or _our wanting._

Comment: And in addition to what @JohnLawler said, *understand* is a verb that does not take a gerund afterwards, but nouns. So you'd say "I understand your request to wait a while longer." and that sounds more grammatical.

Comment: @Neeku: in this case, the gerund is a noun.

Comment: Actually _understand_ **can** take a gerund complement -- with or without subject -- as well as  _that_-complements and embedded question complements. They're different, though: _I understand her kissing him_ doesn't mean the same as _I understand that she kissed him_ or _I understand who she kissed_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Very crafty ordering *her* and *him* that way to avoid prickling the prickly. Well done!